# Errors while creating a dynamic array in a vector class for project

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

I am running into a few errors, a memory error with the back function and failing to pass many of the tests that the program checks for.

I need to get this code working, which is in `Vector.cpp`:

```cpp
#include <stdexcept>
#include "Vector.h"

using namespace std;

void Vector::grow()
{
    const int GROWER = 1.6;
    capacity = capacity * GROWER;
}

Vector::Vector()
{
    capacity = CHUNK;
    n_elems = 0;
    data_ptr = new int[capacity];
    for (size_t i = 0; i < capacity; i++)
    {
        data_ptr[i] = 0;
    }
}

Vector::Vector(const Vector& v)
{
    n_elems = 0;
    capacity = v.capacity;
    data_ptr = new int[capacity];
    for (size_t i = 0; i < capacity; i++)
    {
        data_ptr[i] = v.data_ptr[i];
        n_elems++;
    }
}

Vector& Vector::operator=(const Vector& v)
{
    capacity = v.capacity;
    data_ptr = new int[capacity];
    for (size_t i = 0; i < capacity; i++)
    {
        data_ptr[i] = v.data_ptr[i];
    }
    return *this;
}

Vector::~Vector()
{
    delete[] data_ptr;
}

int Vector::front() const
{
    if (n_elems != 0)
    {
        return data_ptr[0];
    }
    else
    {
        return -1;
        throw range_error("Range Error");
    }
}

int Vector::back() const
{
    if (n_elems != 0)
    {
        return data_ptr[n_elems - 1];
    }
    else
    {
        throw range_error("Range Error");
    }
}

int Vector::at(size_t pos) const
{
    if (pos >= 0 && pos < capacity)
    {
        return data_ptr[pos];
    }
    else
    {
        throw range_error("Range Error");
    }
}

size_t Vector::size() const
{
    return n_elems;
}

bool Vector::empty() const
{
    if (n_elems == 0)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

int& Vector::operator[](size_t pos)
{
    return data_ptr[pos];
}

void Vector::push_back(int item)
{
    grow();
    data_ptr[n_elems - 1] = item;
}

void Vector::pop_back()
{
    if (n_elems >= 0)
    {
        --n_elems;
    }
    else
    {
        throw range_error("Range Error");
    }
}

void Vector::erase(size_t pos)
{
    if (pos >= 0 && pos < capacity)
    {
        for (size_t i = pos; i < capacity; i++)
        {
            data_ptr[i] = data_ptr[i + 1];
        }
        n_elems--;
    }
    else
    {
        throw range_error("Range Error");
    }
}

void Vector::insert(size_t pos, int item)
{
    int moveCount = n_elems - pos;
    grow();
    if (pos >= 0 && pos < capacity)
    {
        for (size_t i = n_elems; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            data_ptr[i] = data_ptr[i - 1];
        }
        data_ptr[pos] = item;
        n_elems++;
    }
    else
    {
        throw range_error("Range Error");
    }
}

void Vector::clear()
{
    n_elems = 0;
}

int* Vector::begin()
{
    if (n_elems == 0)
    {
        return nullptr;
    }
    else
    {
        return data_ptr;
    }
}

int* Vector::end()
{
    if (n_elems == 0)
    {
        return nullptr;
    }
    else
    {
        return (data_ptr + (n_elems - 1));
    }
}

bool Vector::operator==(const Vector& v) const
{
    bool flag = true;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < capacity; i++)
    {
        if (data_ptr[i] == v.data_ptr[i])
        {
            flag = true;
        }
        else
        {
            flag = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    return flag;
}

bool Vector::operator!=(const Vector& v) const
{
    bool flag = true;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < capacity; i++)
    {
        if (data_ptr[i] != v.data_ptr[i])
        {
            flag = true;
        }
        else
        {
            flag = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    return flag;
}
```

To pass these tests, which are located in a file called `testVector.cpp`:

```cpp
#include "Vector.h"
#include "test.h"
#include <stdexcept>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    // Test exceptions
    Vector v;
    throw_(v.at(0), range_error);
    throw_(v.pop_back(), range_error);
    throw_(v.erase(0), range_error);
    throw_(v.front(), range_error);
    throw_(v.back(), range_error);

    // Test adding an element
    v.push_back(1);
    test_(v.size() == 1);
    test_(v.at(0) == 1);
    test_(v[0] == 1);
    test_(v.front() == 1);
    test_(v.back() == 1);
    test_(!v.empty());

    // Add another
    v.push_back(2);
    test_(v.size() == 2);
    test_(v.at(0) == 1);
    test_(v.at(1) == 2);
    test_(v[0] == 1);
    test_(v[1] == 2);
    test_(v.front() == 1);
    test_(v.back() == 2);
    test_(!v.empty());

    // Test iterators
    auto iter = v.begin();
    test_(*iter == 1);
    ++iter;
    test_(*iter == 2);
    ++iter;
    test_(iter == v.end());

    // Test copy and ==
    Vector v2 = v;
    test_(v2.size() == 2);
    test_(v2.at(0) == 1);
    test_(v2.at(1) == 2);
    test_(v2[0] == 1);
    test_(v2[1] == 2);
    test_(v2.front() == 1);
    test_(v2.back() == 2);
    test_(!v2.empty());
    test_(v == v2);

    iter = v2.begin();
    test_(*iter == 1);
    ++iter;
    test_(*iter == 2);
    ++iter;
    test_(iter == v2.end());

    // Test assignment
    Vector v3;
    v3 = v;
    test_(v3.size() == 2);
    test_(v3.at(0) == 1);
    test_(v3.at(1) == 2);
    test_(v3[0] == 1);
    test_(v3[1] == 2);
    test_(v3.front() == 1);
    test_(v3.back() == 2);
    test_(!v3.empty());

    //iter = v3.begin();
    //test_(*iter == 1);
    //++iter;
    //test_(*iter == 2);
    //++iter;
    //test_(iter == v3.end());

    // Test assignment
    v[1] = -2;
    test_(v.back() == -2);
    test_(v.at(1) == -2);
    test_(v[1] == -2);

    // Test pop_back
    v.pop_back();
    test_(v.size() == 1);
    test_(v.front() == 1);
    test_(v.back() == 1);
    test_(v.at(0) == 1);
    test_(v[0] == 1);

    // Test clear and !=
    v.clear();
    test_(v.size() == 0);
    test_(v.empty());
    throw_(v.at(0), range_error);
    throw_(v.pop_back(), range_error);
    throw_(v.erase(0), range_error);
    throw_(v.front(), range_error);
    throw_(v.back(), range_error);
    test_(v != v2);

    // Test erase
    v3.erase(0);
    test_(v3.size() == 1);
    test_(v3.at(0) == 2);
    test_(v3[0] == 2);
    test_(v3.front() == 2);
    test_(v3.back() == 2);

    // Test insert
    //v3.insert(0,1);
    test_(v3.size() == 2);
    test_(v3.at(0) == 1);
    test_(v3[0] == 1);
    test_(v3[1] == 2);
    test_(v3.front() == 1);
    test_(v3.back() == 2);

    // Test grow
    Vector v4;
    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; ++i)
        v4.push_back(i);
    test_(v4.size() == 10);
    test_(v4.front() == 1);
    test_(v4.back() == 10);
    v4.insert(10,11);
    test_(v4.size() == 11);
    test_(v4.front() == 1);
    test_(v4.back() == 11);


    report_();
}
```

Comment: Disreguard the text at the bottom, it would not let me make the post without it.

Comment: So error... What error?

Comment: Where, specifically, is it going wrong? I can see at least that you declared `GROWER` as an `int`, which would make it truncate to 1.

Comment: Also grow changes capacity only, but it doesn't change allocated space (if it actually does multiply by something more than 1)

Comment: A proper [mcve] would be highly desirable, and in fact, within the realm of expectations, including *verbatim* error messages, be they compile time, or run time.

Comment: The true beauty of the [mre] is its a powerful debugging technique. We don't ask for them to make Asker's lives hard. We ask for them because if you start the question-writing process with making a MRE, odds are really good you'll find and fix the bug long before you finish making the MRE and not have to ask the question. Everybody wins!

Comment: @Fatal Downvoted just for "_Disreguard the text at the bottom, it would not let me make the post without it._". Presumably, there was a message, that accompanied said "not allowing to make the post". And, instead of listening to the message, you decided to try to go around it?

Comment: Minor detail in `int Vector::at(size_t pos)`, `size_t` is an unsigned type. That means the `pos >= 0` in `if (pos >= 0 && pos < capacity)` is always true. You may get a compiler warning about this. Don't ignore compiler warnings. They are the compiler telling you that your code may compile, but the logic is suspicious and the program may not run as intended.

Comment: I appreciate everyone, this was my first post so I apologize for the formatting I will do better in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`push_back()` and `insert()` both call `grow()`, which fails to increase the `capacity` because `GROWER` is an `int`, so `1.6` truncates to `1`, and multiplying `capacity * 1` doesn't change its value.  But even if `capacity` were increased properly, the `data_ptr` array is not being re-allocated at all to fit the new `capacity`.

But even if `grow()` were working properly, there is no need to call `grow()` on every insertion of a new element, that defeats the purpose of separating `n_elems` from `capacity` to begin with.  You should grow the array only when `n_elems` has reached `capacity`.

There are many other problems with your class, as well:

- `operator=` is not testing for self-assignment, and is leaking the allocated memory of the old array.  Consider using the [copy-swap idiom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279543/) instead.
- `front()` does not reach the `throw` statement when the array is empty.
- `at()` and `erase()` are performing bounds checking using `capacity` instead of `n_elems`.
- `push_back()` is inserting the new value at the wrong index, and not incrementing `n_elems`.
- `pop_back()` does not `throw` an error when the array is empty, causing `n_elems` to decrement below `0`, which wraps around to the max positive value of `size_t` because `size_t` is *unsigned*.
- `erase()` and `operator==` go out of bounds while iterating the array.
- `begin()` and `end()` should not be returning `nullptr` for an empty array.  And `end()` is returning a pointer to the last element in a non-empty array rather than returning a pointer to 1 past the last element.
- `operator==` and `operator!=` do not perform any bounds checking to make sure the 2 vectors have the same same `n_elems` before iterating their arrays.  And they are comparing element values beyond `n_elems`. Also, `operator!=` is returning the wrong result.

With that said, try something more like this:

```cpp
#include <stdexcept>
#include <algorithm>
#include "Vector.h"

void Vector::grow()
{
    static const float GROWER = 1.6f;
    size_t new_capacity = capacity * GROWER;
    if (new_capacity <= capacity)
        throw std::overflow_error("cant grow capacity");
    int *new_data_ptr = new int[new_capacity];
    std::copy(data_ptr, data_ptr + n_elems, new_data_ptr);
    delete[] data_ptr;
    data_ptr = new_data_ptr;
    capacity = new_capacity;
}

Vector::Vector()
{
    capacity = CHUNK;
    n_elems = 0;
    data_ptr = new int[capacity];
}

Vector::Vector(const Vector& v)
{
    capacity = v.capacity;
    n_elems = v.n_elems;
    data_ptr = new int[capacity];
    std::copy(v.begin(), v.end(), data_ptr);
}

Vector& Vector::operator=(const Vector& v)
{
    if (this != &v)
    {
        Vector temp(v);
        std::swap(capacity, temp.capacity);
        std::swap(n_elems, temp.n_elems);
        std::swap(data_ptr, temp.data_ptr);
    }
    return *this;
}

Vector::~Vector()
{
    delete[] data_ptr;
}

int Vector::front() const
{
    if (n_elems == 0)
        throw std::range_error("Range Error");
    return data_ptr[0];
}

int Vector::back() const
{
    if (n_elems == 0)
        throw std::range_error("Range Error");
    return data_ptr[n_elems - 1];
}

int Vector::at(size_t pos) const
{
    if (pos >= n_elems)
        throw std::range_error("Range Error");
    return data_ptr[pos];
}

size_t Vector::size() const
{
    return n_elems;
}

bool Vector::empty() const
{
    return (n_elems == 0);
}

int& Vector::operator[](size_t pos)
{
    return data_ptr[pos];
}

void Vector::push_back(int item)
{
    if (n_elems == capacity)
        grow();
    data_ptr[n_elems] = item;
    ++n_elems;
}

void Vector::pop_back()
{
    if (n_elems == 0)
        throw std::range_error("Range Error");
    --n_elems;
}

void Vector::erase(size_t pos)
{
    if (pos >= n_elems)
        throw std::range_error("Range Error");
    std::copy(data_ptr + pos + 1, data_ptr + n_elems, data_ptr + pos);
    --n_elems;
}

void Vector::insert(size_t pos, int item)
{
    if (pos > n_elems) // insert at end() is OK...
        throw range_error("Range Error");
    if (n_elems == capacity)
        grow();
    std::copy_backward(data_ptr + pos, data_ptr + n_elems, data_ptr + n_elems + 1);
    data_ptr[pos] = item;
    ++n_elems;
}

void Vector::clear()
{
    n_elems = 0;
}

int* Vector::begin()
{
    return data_ptr;
}

int* Vector::end()
{
    return data_ptr + n_elems;
}

bool Vector::operator==(const Vector& v) const
{
    return (n_elems == v.n_elems) && std::equal(v.begin(), v.end(), data_ptr);
}

bool Vector::operator!=(const Vector& v) const
{
    return !(*this == v);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, sorry for the all over the place post, first time posting on the site.

Answer (score 0):

Your'e missing  declaration of vector here, but I can surmize its structure. First mistake you doing here:

```
const int GROWER = 1.6;  
capacity = capacity * GROWER; // it will never change
```

Reallocation doesn't happen, where it is? You just call upon dietis of Undefined Behaviour.

You either have  to make GROWER `float` or increment size by fixed size. Also it's very unusual for a vector to grow geometrically. And very ineffective to grow on each `push_back`. Instead you have to have  a CAPACITY and ALLOCATED SIZE. Latter may be greater and would grow if `push_back` would increase capacity outside of its limits. You apparently have a number of elements `n_elems` there, but you ignore it?

Many of those are doing too much extra work and don't do what they should.
Like this could actually be

```
data_ptr = new int[capacity] {}; // value initialization
//for (size_t i = 0; i < capacity; i++)
//{
//    data_ptr[i] = 0;
//}
```

Use initialization lists, not side effects. Or you may lose them. Copy constructor also doesn't take in account `n_elems` of v and  may copy garbage, converting it into new elements.

Comparisons  simply wrong, because vectors can have different capacity. E.g.

```
bool Vector::operator==(const Vector& v) const
{
    // check here if either of vectors is empty, 
    // if both are empty, they are equal?
    // if their capacities are unequal, vectors are not equal. Those are shortcuts

    // capacities are same
    for (size_t i = 0; i < capacity; i++ )
        if (data_ptr[i] != v.data_ptr[i])
           return false;

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Highlighting The first point:, my compiler emits the following message: *warning: conversion from 'double' to 'int' changes value from '1.6000000000000001e+0' to '1'* Never ignore the warnings. At the very least inspect the code that the compiler points out and prove to to yourself that it will produce the behaviour you require.

Comment: @user4581301 not all compilers do warn that or not at all times. LittleFloppy Co.'s compilers tends to hide those, unless it's part of initialization list (and older versions contradicted standard and allowed conversions on top level.

Comment: Understood, but if the compiler throws you a bone, take it.